# Sort videos by bitrate

Tags: command-line, python, video, scripts

I have a folder with some 300 videos. I want to sort these by their video bitrate. I use a command 'mediainfo' to obtain the bitrate info of a file . Is it possible to write a script (possibly in python) to sort these videos using this command . I dont know much about scripts, so please do explain :) .Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it a "flat" directory or you need it to be recursively?

Comment: By flat, do you mean whether there are directories inside it?If so,no.there are no directories inside the directory

Comment: Thanks, I have to run, will get back to it later if it is still "open" by then. BTW the mediainfo command is quite slow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly made a python script which calls mediainfo process for each file in a search criteria and sorts then by sorting criteria and prints out the results. Modify for your own needs.

This uses pure string sorting for the values. You could also add `reverse=True` for sorted method if wanted or do whatever you want with the code otherwise. This script requires you to pass arguments with ' around them. Sort criteria argument can be any value that mediainfo returns from the files.

```
import os, sys, glob
import pprint

# Call: python mediainfo_sort.py 'search_criteria' 'sort_criteria'
# Call example: python mediainfo_sort.py '*.avi' 'Bit rate'

files = glob.glob(sys.argv[1])
criteria = sys.argv[2]

# Will have data in format: {'file_path': {'Media Attribute', 'Value'}}
file_datas = {}

# Contruct data by calling mediainfo for all files in 
for file_path in files:
    mediainfo = os.popen('mediainfo "%s"' % file_path).read()
    file_data = {}
    infos = mediainfo.splitlines()
    for info in infos:
        if ':' in info:
            info_split = info.split(':')
            file_data[info_split[0].strip()] = info_split[1].strip()
        file_datas[file_path] = file_data

# function for sorted, uses Media attribute (sort_criteria) value as sorting key
def getKey(item):
    return item[1][criteria]

sorted_files = sorted(file_datas.items(), key=getKey)

# In the end just join the keys (filenames) with newline and print
print '\n'.join([x[0] for x in sorted_files])
```

Comment: It works almost perfect except for when there are whitespaces in the filenames. I dont know why but those with spaces in their name doesnt get their data stored.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I just modified the code to include quotes around %s, like so: `mediainfo = os.popen('mediainfo "%s"' % file_path).read()` which corrects the problem. Eventually this code isn't actually written to be failsafe and it should use [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) instead of popen and catch the possible errors. Consider the code as a starting point. You talked about a python script using mediainfo for sorting files and that is the only thing I did, the rest is up to further development by you or anyone. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may find it helpful to check out [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=878683).

Here's a quick summary as suggested in the comments:

1) install python-nautilus and python-mutagen with `sudo apt-get install python-nautilus python-mutagen`

2) Set your PYTHONPATH variable by following the instructions [here](http://scipher.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/setting-your-pythonpath-environment-variable-linuxunixosx/).

3) Create a directory called python-extensions in ~/.nautilus

4) Download [this python script](http://ubuntuforums.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=181827&d=1295838584) and paste it into ~/.nautilus/python-extensions

5) Restart nautilus with `$ nautilus -q && nautilus &`

I still recommend reading through the thread though, there is a lot of useful information there.

Comment: This if I could have gotten to work wouldve been the easiest solution.But some problem somewhere that I cant figure out

Answer (score 1):

Like I mentioned in my comment, the `mediainfo` command is really, really slow. There are better alternatives I think.

Having said that, here is my version of a python script, that should do the job (python3):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import subprocess

directory = "/path/to/files"

# list the files in the directory
files_tosort = os.listdir(directory)

filedata = []
for file in files_tosort:
    # combine filepath and file, take care of the whitespaces
    filepath = directory+"/"+file; command = "mediainfo "+"'"+filepath+"'"
    # get the file's data
    data = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", command]).decode("utf-8")
    # extract the bitrate from the output
    bitrate = [line[line.find(":")+2:].replace("Kbps", "").replace(" ", "") \
               for line in data.splitlines() if "Bit rate" in line][0]
    # add the found bitrate+filename to he list
    filedata.append((int(bitrate), file))

# sort the list by the bitrate
filedata.sort(key=lambda item: item[0])
# print out
for item in filedata:
    print("bitrate: "+str(item[0])+" Kbps\t file: "+item[1])
```

It creates an output, looking like:

```
bitrate: 606 Kbps    file: film1.avi
bitrate: 731 Kbps    file: film10.avi
bitrate: 790 Kbps    file: film4.avi
bitrate: 802 Kbps    file: film3.avi
bitrate: 845 Kbps    file: film6.avi
bitrate: 919 Kbps    file: film7.avi
bitrate: 984 Kbps    file: film5.avi
bitrate: 1023 Kbps   file: film2.avi
bitrate: 1088 Kbps   file: film8.avi
```

#### Note:

if there is a risk of unreadable files, a "try / except" should be built into the script, to pass in those cases.

#### How to use:

Like with any script, copy the script into an empty file, set the path to the files in the head of the script, save it as `sort_video.py` and run it by the command:

```
python3 /path/to/sort_video.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Using command `mediainfo` and `sort` I'm able to sort about 100+ videos in less than 10s:

```
mediainfo --Inform="General;%OverallBitRate% | %CompleteName% (%OverallBitRate/String%)\n" * | sort -n
```

However, it sorts videos by the global video file bit rate and not only by the video stream bit rate.

## Sample output

```
1091318 | videoA.mkv (1 091 kb/s)
1505121 | videoB.mkv (1 505 kb/s)
8803070 | videoD.mkv (8 803 kb/s)
11192962 | videoC.mkv (11.2 Mb/s)
```

## How it works

Running `mediainfo` with a template through the `Inform` parameter we ask print firstly `OverallBitRate` with only numeric characters.

We ask to look for all file of the folder recursively matching `*`.

Then we pipe all the result into the `sort` command, with the `-n` parameters indicating we are sorting numeric values.

As the later character of `%OverallBitRate%` is non-numeric (space is not a numeric character), `sort -n` will only consider firsts numeric characters.
That's means that `sort -n` with look to digits before the `|` separation which separate the overall bit rate and the file name.

## Notes

Per line, `mediainfo` seem to be limited to only one section using the `--Inform` parameters. So if FileName would be printed, you can only get the OverallBitRate instead of BitRate (which is really close) as `BitRate` is in `Video` section and `OverallBitRate` however is in the `General` section as the file name is.

The difference is that `OverallBitRate` also contain audio bit rate along the video.

As seen, that's not really a python script: `mediainfo` itself could do most of the work making the python script non required.